# Is there a way to exclude lines from looping in a while loop?

Tags: php

I don't want a couple lines to be affected by the while loop. Is there any way to accomplish it?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
    echo '<td>'.$total_N.'</td>'; //not to be looped
    echo '<td>'.'&nbsp'.'</td>'; //not to be looped

    $total +=$row['n'];

    echo '<tr><td>'.$row['l_numb'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['p_numb'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['n'].'</td><td>'.$row['g'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: move them to outside the loop! can't u do that?

Comment: that's the problem. they must be in the loop, but not to be looped.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If they must be "in the loop" but "not looped" then comment them out xD

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare a `$count` variable use an `if` statement to check when the loop count reaches the particular line you require:

```
$count = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    if ($count !== 5 && $count !== 10)
    {     

        echo '<td>'.$total_N.'</td>'; //not to be looped
        echo '<td>'.'&nbsp'.'</td>'; //not to be looped
        $total +=$row['n'];
        echo '<tr><td>'.$row['l_numb'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['p_numb'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['n'].'</td><td>'.$row['g'].'</td></tr>';

    }

    $count++;
}
```

In the above example, the statements inside the loop will not be processed for the lines 5 and 10 (the loop will still execute, but it won't get into the if block as the conditions will not be satisfied). That's just an example -- you can modify it to achieve what you actually want.

Comment: Or use any other condition, as long as you can filter out the items you don't want to be affected by the loop. Anyway +1.